# SQLite: unable to open database

Tags: sqlite, ionic, cordova-plugin

### Aplicativo utilizando ionic/cordova (SQLite).

Estou utilizando o plugin $cordovaSQLite dentro no app.
Quando eu dou um save, modifico algo no projeto, a simulação no brownser (GoogleChrome) fica extremamente lenta para carregar e quando carrega aparece os seguintes erros:

> unable to open database, failed to start transaction (5 database is
>   locked)
>
> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'openDatabase' on 'Window':
>   unable to open database, failed to start transaction (5 database is
>   locked)

É desta forma em que eu crio e abro meu banco:

```
db = window.openDatabase("FidelisApp", "1.0", "DB Teste", "5000");
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (userID text primary key, correio text, name text, phone num, senha num, cep num, endereco text, bairro text, cidade text, estado text, pais text)");
```

Um das formas como eu uso o meu banco SQLite:

```
var query = "INSERT INTO users (userID, correio, name, phone, senha, cep, endereco, bairro, cidade, estado, pais) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [userData.uid, user.correio, user.name, user.phone, user.senha, '', '', '', '', '', '']).then(function(result) {
                console.log("INSERT ID -> " + result.insertId);
            }, function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
```

Primeira em que estou usando o SQLite, me ajudem!

Comment: ps: nem fechar o browser eu consigo! o.O"

Comment: tem mais detalhes do log de quando é emitido esse erro? tente diferenciar também quando esta no contexto webbrowser e no mobile. por exemplo: if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
                database = $cordovaSQLite.openDB('DB Teste', 'default');
            } else {
                database = window.openDatabase('DB Teste', '1.0', 'Cordova', 200000);
            } -- tente identificar também se o erro somente ocorre nas transações do browser ou quando esta testando no aplicativo também.

Comment: Consegue colocar o controller.js e/ou service.js que está a utilizar para o fluxo de salvar ? De preferência todo o fluxo, deste um click em um botão para salvar por exemplo ate a execução deste método de execute. Talvez vc tenha o codigo no github e queira mostrar também.